# embedding resources in python scripts

Tags: python, embedded-resource

I'd like to figure out how to embed binary content in a python script. For instance, I don't want to have any external files around (images, sound, ... ), I want all this content living inside of my python scripts.

Little example to clarify, let's say I got this small snippet:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

embedded_resource = StringIO(open("Lenna.png", "rb").read())
im = Image.open(embedded_resource)
im.show()

im_sharp = im.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
im_sharp.show()
```

As you can see, the example is reading the external file 'Lenna.png'

[image]

**Question**

How to proceed to embed "Lenna.png" as a resource (variable) into my python script. What's the fastest way to achieve this simple task using python?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is converting the image into "raw" data and storing that in a variable. Not sure if that is very pythonic though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the following class rather useful for embedding resources in your program. To use it, call the `package` method with paths to the files that you want to embed. The class will print out a `DATA` attribute that should be used to replace the one already found in the class. If you want to add files to your pre-built data, use the `add` method instead. To use the class in your program, make calls to the `load` method using context manager syntax. The returned value is a `Path` object that can be used as a filename argument to other functions or for the purpose of directly loading the reconstituted file. See this [SMTP Client](http://pastebin.com/bRZuq72L) for example usage.

```
import base64
import contextlib
import pathlib
import pickle
import pickletools
import sys
import zlib


class Resource:

    """Manager for resources that would normally be held externally."""

    WIDTH = 76
    __CACHE = None
    DATA = b''

    @classmethod
    def package(cls, *paths):
        """Creates a resource string to be copied into the class."""
        cls.__generate_data(paths, {})

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, *paths):
        """Include paths in the pre-generated DATA block up above."""
        cls.__preload()
        cls.__generate_data(paths, cls.__CACHE.copy())

    @classmethod
    def __generate_data(cls, paths, buffer):
        """Load paths into buffer and output DATA code for the class."""
        for path in map(pathlib.Path, paths):
            if not path.is_file():
                raise ValueError('{!r} is not a file'.format(path))
            key = path.name
            if key in buffer:
                raise KeyError('{!r} has already been included'.format(key))
            with path.open('rb') as file:
                buffer[key] = file.read()
        pickled = pickle.dumps(buffer, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        optimized = pickletools.optimize(pickled)
        compressed = zlib.compress(optimized, zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
        encoded = base64.b85encode(compressed)
        cls.__print("    DATA = b'''")
        for offset in range(0, len(encoded), cls.WIDTH):
            cls.__print("\\\n" + encoded[
                slice(offset, offset + cls.WIDTH)].decode('ascii'))
        cls.__print("'''")

    @staticmethod
    def __print(line):
        """Provides alternative printing interface for simplicity."""
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    @classmethod
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def load(cls, name, delete=True):
        """Dynamically loads resources and makes them usable while needed."""
        cls.__preload()
        if name not in cls.__CACHE:
            raise KeyError('{!r} cannot be found'.format(name))
        path = pathlib.Path(name)
        with path.open('wb') as file:
            file.write(cls.__CACHE[name])
        yield path
        if delete:
            path.unlink()

    @classmethod
    def __preload(cls):
        """Warm up the cache if it does not exist in a ready state yet."""
        if cls.__CACHE is None:
            decoded = base64.b85decode(cls.DATA)
            decompressed = zlib.decompress(decoded)
            cls.__CACHE = pickle.loads(decompressed)

    def __init__(self):
        """Creates an error explaining class was used improperly."""
        raise NotImplementedError('class was not designed for instantiation')
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the accepted answer & upvoted. I don't really like to do that once I had accepted the other answer but yours will be really handy for my purposes

Comment: Thank you for the vote of confidence! Hopefully, the reference program will provide sufficient example on how to use the class. If you want the resource files to linger around after they have been loaded, you can change `delete=True` to `delete=False` in the `load` method, or you can call the method and pass `False` as its second argument. One inventive use of the class is to imbed other modules you have written in your program that are needed as dependencies. The SMTP Client does that so that it can load a thread-safe wrapper around the classes in `tkinter`. Overall, it worked rather well.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to go about this is converting your picture into a python string, and have it in a separate file called something like `resources.py`, then you simply parse it.

If you are looking to embed the whole thing inside a single binary, then you're looking at something like [py2exe](http://py2exe.org/). [Here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) is an example embedding external files

In the first scenario, you could even use `base64` to (de)code the picture, something like this:

```
import base64
file = open('yourImage.png'); 
encoded = base64.b64encode(file.read())
data = base64.b64decode(encoded) # Don't forget to file.close() !
```

Comment: Av4t4r I was going to post the [base64](http://kb.worldviz.com/articles/878) solution right now :) . Yeah, that's what I was looking for, thanks.