# Problems with Converting a .py to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a .py to a .exe with auto-py-to-exe.

I get this error when i run the .exe

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "random_word\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "random_word\random_word.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "random_word\utils\utils.py", line 28, in get_api_keys
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\phili\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI162522\\random_word\\config.yml'
[15844] Failed to execute script main
```

Comment: With only tracebacks it is almost always hard to tell where goes wrong. Please provide more information that might be related to your problem. E.g.: the command you entered, some code snippets, version information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using another way to generate random words.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error you are getting is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\phili\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI162522\\random_word\\config.yml'` I am assuming that inside of your python script you hardcoded the filepath to `config.yml`. Once you compile your python script and move it to a different directory, the script will not be able to find the file anymore and yield the FileNotFoundError.

To fix the issue you can either provide a command line flag that provides the filepath to `config.yml` or you can embedd the file into your python script as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337630/embedding-resources-in-python-scripts).

Comment: I dont think it has...

import os
import random
import time
from random_word import RandomWords
r = RandomWords()

    # Gmail Generate
    gmail_user = r.get_random_word(hasDictionaryDef="true", includePartOfSpeech="noun,verb", minCorpusCount=1, maxCorpusCount=10, minDictionaryCount=1, maxDictionaryCount=10, minLength=5, maxLength=10)
    gmail_user2 = r.get_random_word(hasDictionaryDef="true", includePartOfSpeech="noun,verb", minCorpusCount=1, maxCorpusCount=10, minDictionaryCount=1, maxDictionaryCount=10, minLength=5, maxLength=10)

Comment: Ok, I checked your imports and reread your error log. It seems that you need to provide a config.yml in the same directory as your newly compiled .exe file. This config.yml needs to set a field `API_KEY`. The file where your error happens is at https://github.com/vaibhavsingh97/random-word/blob/master/random_word/random_word.py. You can see that the random_word module tries to read this config.yml file from the same directory as the python script you ran it from. The github page also explains how you attain this API_KEY: https://github.com/vaibhavsingh97/random-word#development